# How to configure creation of new files in IDEA Intellij

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

Is it possible to configure the creation of new JavaScript-Files in Intellij?

e.g. I would like to have something like:

1. Klick at right mouse-button -> new -> JavaScript
2. Jira creates something like this:

   describe("", function () {
       it("", function () {
       });
   });

These are actually Jasmine Unit-Tests.

Comment: Jira? Do you mean IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure new templates in *Settings/Editor/File and Code templates*.

Click the green plus button, enter the template name, extension and its definition. The definition can look something like this:

```
describe("${DESCRIBE}", function () {
    it("${IT}", function () {

    });
});
```

Then you can choose this template when creating a new file. If you use placeholders like `${DESCRIBE}`, IntelliJ will prompt you to specify values for them along with the filename.

Below are some screenshots illustrating the process:

[image]

[image]